# PolyGerrit - Cors issue

Tags: cors, gerrit

So I just upgraded my Gerrit to 2.14.4 which is currently the latest stable version. After upgarding I tried using the new UI i.e. PolyGerrit.

However with PolyGerrit, my server keeps on throwing:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://abc.testing.com' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Is there anyway to disable Cors in GERRIT? I tried setting CORS to false as below and it didnt help:

```
[site]
               allowOriginRegex = false
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

CORS issue is caused by the browser . Basically , when you send a request to fetch a resource(www.xyz.com) which is different from your browser url(say localhost:8081)  The browser  will require some headers in the response for it to forward  the response  to the web page . To avoid this issue , a quick fix is disabling CORS in your browser . For example in chrome :- you can run chrome with the the flag --disable-web-security

Comment: I understand but there should be a better solution rather than updating a browser to run without web security.